# GPUReport shows no data with Metal in a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, metal

I am creating a metal app where the primary renderer is a custom UIView that has a CAMetalLayer as a sublayer of it. This works just fine for rendering but nothing is showing up in the FPS debugger and I would really like to have that information.

This debugger I speak of is found by going to the monitors section of the left panel and it is at the bottom below the CPU monitor etc.

I am using a CADisplayLink to trigger my rendering updates and I suppose I could work in something there but it would sure be nice to get back to the easy to access GPU and CPU ms times and usage.

Is there anyway to attach my UIView so that this debugger appears?

Comment: Turns out that this is a bug that has been around for awhile now the "solution" can be found here until Xcode fixes their error. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23795 you just have to edit your scheme so that frame capture is not enabled.